# How to split a string into array of characters?

Tags: google-sheets

Say there's a cell **A1** in which the text content is "**丟內樓某**". How could I split the text into an array such as ["丟", "內", "樓", "某"]?

Since this is a string of Chinese characters and there's no blank within it as a delimiter, I don't think I can use the [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) function.

Is there any other means?

Comment: Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have different feature sets. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states _"Don't use it for the Google Drive Excel files editor."_ and the [microsoft-excel] tag description explicitly states _"Questions with this tag should ONLY be about how Microsoft Excel interacts with a specific web application. General questions about Microsoft Excel are off-topic here but can be asked at Super User."_ Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.

Comment: @doubleunary, you are right. When I noticed that, they have already answered it both for google sheets and ms excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
=regexextract(A1,regexreplace(A1,"(.)","($1)"))
```

Or:

```
=split(regexreplace(A1,"(.)","$1ζ"),"ζ")
```

Or:

```
=arrayformula(mid(A1,sequence(1,len(A1)),1))
```

Comment: To clarify: all formulas in this answer are for Google Sheets, and none of them will work as-is in Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by Joshua Tzucker [here](https://joshuatz.com/posts/2021/google-sheets-split-string-into-characters/):

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1&"","(?s)(.{1})","$1"&CHAR(127)),"'","''"),CHAR(127))
```

Rather complicated, but it's still a one-liner.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it seems not an elegant solution, especially since there's a CHAR(127) that looks hard-coded.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a simple `regexextract()` by building the regex with `rept()`, like this:

```
=regexextract(A1, rept("(.)", len(A1)))
```

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: [rept()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134) works fine in Google Sheets.